# Trying to reverse the JavaScript trigger of an HTML/ CSS switcher

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML, CSS switcher which is working well.

However - I'd like the effect to be opposite so that there is NO text at all, but when the switcher is swiped then text (via a DIV) is trigger - so basically the opposite way around to how it currently is.

Any ideas how to do this? I have tried playing around with the 'hide' class but I can't get it to work...

Here's the code:

```js
function toggleDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 51px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "BY COUNTRY";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "SHOW TEXT";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0.5px;
  background: #A1A1A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 145px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #999999;
}

.triggeredDiv {
  display: block;
}

.triggeredDiv.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                 <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                 <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
             </label>
</div>

<div class="triggeredDiv">
  Show Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `class` name from `hidden` to `shown` and adjusted the `JavaScript` accordingly.

```css
.triggeredDiv {
  display: none;
}

.triggeredDiv.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function toggleDiv() {
  var triggeredDiv = document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv');
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    triggeredDiv.classList.remove('shown');
  } else {
    triggeredDiv.classList.add('shown');
  }
}
document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 51px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "BY COUNTRY";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "SHOW TEXT";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0.5px;
  background: #A1A1A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 145px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #999999;
}

.triggeredDiv {
  display: none;
}

.triggeredDiv.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
         </label>
</div>

<div class="triggeredDiv">
  Show Text
</div>
```

Comment: `.hidden` and `display: block;`?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I adjusted the class name from `hidden` to `shown`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the logic and call the function initially.

```
function toggleDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}
toggleDiv() // initial call. You may need to wait DOMContentLoaded
```

```js
function toggleDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}
toggleDiv()
document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 51px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "BY COUNTRY";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "SHOW TEXT";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0.5px;
  background: #A1A1A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 145px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #999999;
}

.triggeredDiv {
  display: block;
}

.triggeredDiv.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                 <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                 <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
             </label>
</div>

<div class="triggeredDiv">
  Show Text
</div>
```

Comment: Reversing the logic is the only thing needed in this case here. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery, `hide` text to begin with then `show` when on country.

```js
$('.triggeredDiv').hide();

function toggleDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    console.log("hidden")
    $('.triggeredDiv').hide();
  } else {
    console.log("shown")
    $('.triggeredDiv').show();
  }
}
document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 51px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "BY COUNTRY";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "SHOW TEXT";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #dfe4ea;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0.5px;
  background: #A1A1A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 145px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #999999;
}

.triggeredDiv {
  display: block;
}

.triggeredDiv .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                 <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                 <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
             </label>
</div>

<div class="triggeredDiv">
  Show Text
</div>
```

Comment: OP does not use jquery. This is a bad practice to promote a huge library for show/hide elements.

Comment: Did he mention anywhere he is not open to `JQuery`?! its an option... use it or not, doesnt mean its wrong!! Plus he clearly says he used it and it didn't work @YuryTarabanko

Comment: Ok but I still think this answer is bad. :) Promoting to use (and load) a huge library... A complete rewrite using say Angular is also "an option".